# Does a new season reset your win streak?

Tags: hearthstone

When a new month comes along, your Hearthstone rank gets reset.  If you had a win streak going the day before, are not higher than rank 6 (can you even get to rank 5 after a reset?) and win your first game, will you get 2 stars?

Answer (score 8):

According to [this PSA](https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/68npwj/til_win_streaks_dont_carry_over_ranked_seasons/), no, win streaks will not carry over between seasons.

> I just realized a few days ago that it's not necessarily obvious whether or not win streaks carry over between ranked months. I worked up a winstreak last night and then logged off. Just played rn and won my first match. No bonus star. I'm not that surprised, but I wasn't sure what would happen.